# How to sample random points uniformly distributed on the surface of a tri-axial ellipsoid?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, analytic-geometry, sampling

A straightforward solution to this problem is:

> Generating a random point [x_0, y_0, z_0] on a unit sphere according
>   to the following steps:
>
> - *Choose*
>
>   a random number r, which -1 < r < 1
>
>   a random number t, which  0 < t < 2*pi
> - *Set*
>
>   x_0 = sqrt(1-r^2)*cos(t)
>
>   y_0 = sqrt(1-r^2)*sin(t)
>
>   z_0 = r
>
> Then mapping this point onto a tri-axial ellipsoid surface (with A > B > C
>   semi-axes) as follows:
>
> - *Define*
>
>   x = A * x_0
>
>   y = B * y_0
>
>   z = C * z_0
> - *Calculate*
>
>   R =
>     sqrt{(B^2)(C^2)((x_0)^2) + (A^2)(C^2)((y_0)^2)+(A^2)(B^2)((z_0)^2)}
> - *Keep the point with probability*
>
>   P = R / A*B
>
>   else reject it and start over.
>
> ---
>
> Also, a similar solution is discussed in
>   [How to generate points uniformly distributed on the surface of an ellipsoid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973101/how-to-generate-points-uniformly-distributed-on-the-surface-of-an-ellipsoid?newreg=6b61447a9d8942cd94bba07515bde6f7)
>   in more detail.

---

I have some confusion with the last line of the described solution (i.e., *Keep points with probability P, and reject others*). What this exactly mean, and why?

I write an algorithm based on this method in C++ language, but I'm not sure that in the last line (**Keep the point with probability P...**),

- the probability "p([x, y, z]) = R([x, y, z]) / A*B" must be equal to "P" (which calculated for [x_0, y_0, z_0]) to keep the point,
- or I have to generate the second random point [x', y', z'] and check the condition "p([x', y', z']) = P" to decide if the point [x, y, z] should be accepted/rejected (like the latest step of the well-known "rejection method" for sampling),
- or anything else? (I'm totally wrong and that phrase has a different meaning)

I would be very grateful if anyone could clearly explain and help me with this.

Comment: Chose a random number $0<q<1$. If $q<P$ then output the point $[x,y,z]$. Otherwise loop through the whole algorithm again.

Answer (score 1):

Although the axis-stretching transformation from the solid sphere to the solid ellipsoid preserves volume, it does not preserve surface area when viewed as a map from the surface of the sphere to the surface of the ellipsoid.  [Rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) is one way to compensate for this.